# Wordpress tag page index by google

Tags: wordpress, indexing, tags

Is there any wordpress plugin that would help me to choose what tag page to index. 
There is a lot of tags on my page with noindex. But some of them are worthy and able to be index by Google bot.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Yoast Seo ( https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/ ) or All in One Seo Pack ( https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/ ) or something similar! With these plugins you can manage your sitemap and you can choose which pages must be included in indexes and which not!

Comment: I do not think there is any possibility to get indexed only specific tags is there?

Comment: @Matik try this: https://www.google.it/amp/s/kb.yoast.com/kb/how-do-i-noindex-urls/amp/?client=safari